# Laravel installation via Composer results in connection timeout error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I want to create a new Laravel project using Composer. I have installed Composer and successfully ran the command `composer global require laravel/installer`. However, when I tried to run `laravel new <project-name>`, I encountered an error:

> A connection timeout was encountered. If you intend to run Composer
> without connecting to the internet, run the command again prefixed
> with COMPOSER_DISABLE_NETWORK=1 to make Composer run in offline mode.

I verified that my internet connection was functioning properly. I deleted the files created by the command and tried again, but the same error occurred. I noticed that the process "Downloading laravel/pint (v1.15.0)" does not complete and results in the same error.

I then ran the commands `composer clear-cache` and `composer install` in the project directory (which contains the created files), but these actions did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can try check internet connection/proxy or you can specify timeout like this

```
COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=2000 composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel yourProjectName
```